# Prolog assigning "\r" when 13 is used

Tags: list, prolog

Started learning prolog this past week and am having trouble with how variables are assigned in this particular case where it is a list containing one element inside of a list.

```
?- X = [[13]].
X = ["\r"]
```

Why is prolog assigning ["\r"]? What can be done so it assigns that actual value?

Comment: Double quotes in SWI prolog represent a list of character codes in SWI Prolog. So, `"\r"` is identically equivalent to `[13]`. Just as `"abc"` is identically equivalent to `[97,98,99]`.

Comment: Also, Prolog doesn't "assign" variable. It "unifies" them. It is an important distinction. Your query could be written as `?- [[13]] = X.` equally well, but if you think of this as assignment then it seems wrong.

Comment: But `[[13]] = ["\r"]` yields false in SWI Prolog, so these two things are not the same in all Prologs.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer They would be the same in "traditional" mode: `$ swipl -q --traditional
?- [[13]] = ["\r"].
true.`

Answer (score 1):

It is exactly that "actual value". It just shows up differently on the top level.

In most Prologs, a list of small integers and a list of character codes are identical. In other words, those two, `[13]` and `"\r"`, cannot be told apart. So, when you put a `13` in a list, your particular Prolog thinks you meant to make a list of (ASCII) codes, and since 13 is the value of the carriage return, this is what it shows you. (Here, a string of characters enclosed in double quotes is just another way of representing that list of small integers). But this really depends on the implementation. Here is what my Prolog (SWI-Prolog v7) tells me:

```
?- X = [[13]].
X = [[13]].
```

Just to confuse you even more, you could have written the above in another way: as a list of character codes in `0'` notation:

```
?- X = [0'\r], Y = [0'\xd].
X = Y, Y = [13].
```

(Not sure what you are going to see: consult the documentation of you implementation for such details.)

The `0'` notation is a way to directly take the numerical value of a character: `0'a` is the same as `97`. So, the `X` above is the numerical value of the carriage return, which is 13, which is `0xD` in hexadecimal.